# Why is wp-cron taking up so many resources?

Tags: wordpress, fastcgi

From /var/logs/httpd/error-log:

```
[Thu Apr 22 01:41:15 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/wp-cron.php with wrapper /usr/bin/php-cgi  
[Thu Apr 22 01:41:15 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: server /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/wp-cron.php(17999) started  
...The previous line shows up 8661 times...
```

What's in Cron?

```
Apr 22, 2010 @ 18:25 (1271960731)    Twice Daily    wp_version_check  
Apr 22, 2010 @ 18:25 (1271960731)    Twice Daily    wp_update_plugins  
Apr 22, 2010 @ 18:25 (1271960731)    Twice Daily    wp_update_themes  
Apr 23, 2010 @ 12:21 (1272025294)    Once Daily wp_scheduled_delete
```

Running CentoOS 5/plesk 9.3/php as FastCGI/suExec with WP 2.9.2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what resources is it taking up? I don't see anything along the lines of process/cpu utilization, memory use, system slowness, etc

Comment: could this have anything to do with it?  


`[Wed Apr 21 17:37:43 2010] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: WordPress database error Table 'xxxwordp.xxx_commentmeta' doesn't exist for query SELECT comment_id FROM xxx_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_trash_meta_time' AND meta_value < '1269290263' made by do_action_ref_array, call_user_func_array, wp_scheduled_delete`

Comment: warren, if the line shows up 8661 times within seconds it is taking up resources.

Comment: yes, the database errors would have something to do with it. if your cron job waiting on the DB results, but not getting them, it may be re-trying over and over again

Comment: i guess the next step is find out the sql script to add the commentmeta table and see if the problem goes away. thanks!

Comment: @Gaia you've requested to move this to Stackoverflow. I think you'll have to add some programming related details before I can close and move the question. Thanks!

Comment: Leave it here if you see fit, but I believe this issue is clearly programming related because wp-cron is Wordpress' imitation of a system's cron feature, therefore a program, and not a OS feature.

Answer (score 1):

is the request to `wp-cron.php` coming from the local host, or somewhere else? if the former, it looks like WordPress’s timing is doing something wrong (see `spawn_cron()` in `wp-includes/cron.php`), if the latter — disable access to it via `.htaccess` or similar.

Comment: it is coming from the local host. i guess the next step is find out  the sql script to add the commentmeta table and see if the problem goes away. thanks